# Assign attribute and variable serial number

Tags: process, simulation, arena-simulation

I've been stuck on how to correctly assign a variable to 4 different cars in arena. I have decide module in which I add 4 groups in percent 24 , 27 , 23 and 26 then I assign to each of theme an attribute and a variable serial number.

The thing is when I get to the last part and want each of the entities to take different paths through their specific attribute variable value. When I add another decide module in the end and specify the 4 different variables or attributes neither of them take the correct way back. The only way it works is if a copy the 4 different assign modules and also put them at the end, but this is not what I want. Shouldn't the entities already have the label on them even in the end? How do I do it?